# Return all derived models in EF Core (TPH )

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a task which requires me to return all models from a table using inheritance (TPH).

I have a model class called `WorkflowInstance` and a derived class `CustomWorkflowInstance` (which has a string property). There is a discriminator of course.

I want to know of a way where I can return all the elements without considering the discriminator

```
public class WorkflowInstance : Entity, ITenantScope, ICorrelationScope
{
    public WorkflowInstance();

    public SimpleStack<ActivityScope> Scopes { get; set; }
    public SimpleStack<ScheduledActivity> ScheduledActivities { get; set; }
    public WorkflowFault? Fault { get; set; }
    public HashSet<BlockingActivity> BlockingActivities { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, object?>> ActivityData { get; set; }
    public WorkflowOutputReference? Output { get; set; }
    public WorkflowInputReference? Input { get; set; }
    public Variables Variables { get; set; }
    public Instant? FaultedAt { get; set; }
    public Instant? CancelledAt { get; set; }
    public Instant? FinishedAt { get; set; }
    public Instant? LastExecutedAt { get; set; }
    public Instant CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? ContextId { get; set; }
    public string? ContextType { get; set; }
    public string CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public WorkflowStatus WorkflowStatus { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public string? TenantId { get; set; }
    public string DefinitionId { get; set; }
    public ScheduledActivity? CurrentActivity { get; set; }
    public string? LastExecutedActivityId { get; set; }
}

public class CustomWorkflowInstance : WorkflowInstance
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<WorkflowInstance>()
             .HasDiscriminator<int>("Discriminator")
             .HasValue(0)
             .HasValue<WorkflowInstance>(0)
             .HasValue<CustomWorkflowInstance>(1);}
```

[image]

I want to find a way to query the table as it is meaning adding where clause FinishedAt > etc (the issue is that UserId exist only in derived class but all the data is in base class where discriminator always equals 0)
so by doing select * from WorkflowInstanceTABLE where Used="xx" it automatically adds the where discriminator = 1 (because I wrote _dbContext.CustomWorkflowInstance which contains the userId in question.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. The whole point of TPH (and TPT) is that `Set<WorkflowInstance>()` returns all  base and derived items (everything which *is a* base entity).

Comment: the WorkflowInstance is actually from dll and I had to add a string property so I created CustomWorkflowInstance and added the new property. I thought by doing set<WorkflowInstance> I would return everything but it only returns that model and not everything (in sql log, the query has where discriminator = ) and that is not what I want

Comment: `var workflows = db.Set<WorkflowInstance>()` -> `var customWorkflows = workflows.OfType<CustomWorkflowInstance>()`.

Comment: Even if you return all types by using `Set<WorkflowInstance>()` (your only option) then the query will contain a discriminator filter to make sure EF will only receive discriminator values it can handle. After all, the table may contain anything,

Comment: What EF Core version are you using? Looks like you are observing pre EFC 5.0 behavior, because in EFC 5.0 [it has been changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20EF%20Core%20now%20regards%20discriminators%20as,if%20your%20discriminator%20column%20might%20hold%20unknown%20values.) and now by default the discriminator is considered complete and no filter is included in the query. Shortly, you have to upgrade to EFC 5.0+ to get that behavior, there is nothing you could do in previous EFC versions.

Comment: @GertArnold Exactly and that is my issue, basically I don't want the 'where discriminator = ' (for my business purposes I need to return everything.

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm using ef core 5.0

Comment: Hmm, then it should work according to the documentation. Is `WorkflowInstance` the root base entity of the hierarchy? Or it is derived from another base entity? It would be easier if you provide small but enough to reproduce the issue chunk of code. Currently we are just blindly guessing, which won't help.

Comment: @AmineMraihi Actually, what I said isn't true for EF-core 5, there's no discriminator filter in the query when getting the base type. Which is sad, IMO, because EF will throw an exception if there are alien discriminator values in the database. Reality isn't always as clean as EF thinks.

Comment: @IvanStoev WorkflowInstance belongs to Elsa workflows (Elsa is a worlflow engine), I needed to add properties to the model so I created an new model called CustomWorkflowInstance that inherits from WorkflowInstance. `public class CustomWorkflowInstance : WorkflowInstance
    {
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    }` and I want to do a query where UserId = 'xxx' from the table without adding the discriminator (keep in mind that discrminator always takes the value of workflowInstance and for what Im doing it needs to be like that, and that is why where discriminator returns wrong.

Comment: @Gert But they provided [an option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration) to use the more restrictive mode if you wish (`.IsComplete(false)`), so nothing so sad, just the default behavior change :)

Comment: @Ivan Oh dear, missed that one. Good to know :)

Comment: @AmineMraihi Maybe you should add a comprehensive [mre] to your question. Don't give all details in comments, but [edit] your question.

Comment: @GertArnold I have updated my question with more details

Comment: That simply means that your model and the data don't match. EF won't store a `CustomWorkflowInstance` with a `Discriminator` value of `0`. And, likewise, never materialize it. Not sure what you're doing here. Something's got to give, the data or the model.

Comment: @GertArnold, As a matter of fact, yes I confirm. So I had to improvise, I created an sql view based on the existing table, added it to dotnet application with DbUp. Created a new model WorkflowInstanceVIEW and mapped it to that view. And from now on when I want to retreive data I use it, otherwise I use WorkflowInstance or CustomWorkflowInstance